# What does the ".000Z" of "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z" mean?

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting, timezone

I've gotten a response from one application with the following date & time format:

> yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z

I need date and time for a report I have to present. What does the .000Z mean? What do I need to do to get the time according to a region using javascript?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

.000 is the fraction of a second and Z indicates UTC timezone.

How you convert to your local time will depend on which programming language you prefer, but for example Perl has standard modules for parsing and formatting times.

Comment: Chris, i'm currently usin javascript. I'll update the question.

Comment: just to mention that UTC is not a timezone actually,
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html
```Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is often interchanged or confused with Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). But GMT is a time zone and UTC is a time standard.```